# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - 'other' has different root

Tags: java, eclipse, illegalargumentexception, vert.x

I am writing a java application using Vertx. I am trying to deploy one of my modules using the following code. But I am facing IllegalArgumentException, which I am not able to solve.

Part of my main class:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + File.separator + "modules" + File.separator
                + "agents-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-mod.zip");
        InputStream agf = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + File.separator + "conf" + File.separator
                + "dbproperties1.json");
            String json = IOUtils.toString( agf );
            LOGGER.debug("db json:::"+json);
        JsonObject configprop =  new JsonObject(json);
        pm.deployModuleFromZip(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + File.separator + "modules" + File.separator
                + "agents-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-mod.zip", configprop, 1,
                new AsyncResultHandler<String>() {
                    public void handle(AsyncResult<String> asyncResult) {
                        LOGGER.debug("Deployment agnet ID dddd");
                        if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                            LOGGER.debug("Deployment agnet ID is "
                                    + asyncResult.result());
                        } else {
                            LOGGER.debug("Deployment agnet  ID is null "
                                    + asyncResult.result());
                            asyncResult.cause().printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }); 
        agf.close();
```

The error in the console is as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'other' has different root
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.relativize(WindowsPath.java:392)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.relativize(WindowsPath.java:44)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.setPathResolver(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1128)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$2000(DefaultPlatformManager.java:55)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$18.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1276)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:171)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:366)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: `new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + ...` - does that actually work?

Comment: As a side note, long variable names won't bite you. All they'll do is make your code easier to read.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299604/creating-a-path-between-two-paths-in-java-using-the-path-class

Comment: immibis - Yeah FileInputStream is working. I am deploying two more modules using the same syntax. But I am facing problems with this particular module only.

Comment: QPaysTaxes - Apologies! In a hurry, I wrote a test code. I simply copied it to here. I will keep in mind next time to give the right names for the variables.

Comment: MrWiggles - I have been on that link. Didn't solve my problem in anyway. I am working on Windows. And most of the solutions there are for Linux platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my case.

For a vertx project, there will be mod.json file in the project. It should have the following json.

```
{
  "main": "com.company.agent.Manager",
  "preserve-cwd": true
}
```

`"preserve-cwd": true` does the help.