# maven build fails but allure report is generated

Tags: java, maven, allure

My Allure local report gets generated but the maven build fails. Can anyone help me fix this issue? Attached here is my POM and the maven failure message.
POM:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
    <hudson.version>2.1.2</hudson.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.16</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <selenium.version>2.45.0</selenium.version>
    <selenium-driver.version>2.44.0</selenium-driver.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <acceptance.framework.acceptance>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</acceptance.framework.acceptance>
    <acceptance.shared.acceptance>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</acceptance.shared.acceptance>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.1</commons-lang3.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.4.20</allure.version>
    <allure-maven-plugin.version>2.2</allure-maven-plugin.version>
    <webdriver.ie64.driver>${settings.localRepository}/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver-server-x64/${selenium-driver.version}/selenium-ie-driver-server-x64-${selenium-driver.version}.exe</webdriver.ie64.driver>
    <webdriver.ie32.driver>${settings.localRepository}/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver-server-32/${selenium-driver.version}/selenium-ie-driver-server-32-${selenium-driver.version}.exe</webdriver.ie32.driver>
    <webdriver.chrome.driver>${settings.localRepository}/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver-server/${selenium-driver.version}/selenium-chrome-driver-server-${selenium-driver.version}.exe</webdriver.chrome.driver>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cccis.testing.acceptance</groupId>
        <artifactId>acceptance-shared</artifactId>
        <version>${acceptance.shared.acceptance}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cccis.testing.acceptance</groupId>
        <artifactId>acceptance-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${acceptance.framework.acceptance}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${allure-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver-server-x64</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-driver.version}</version>
        <type>exe</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver-server-32</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-driver.version}</version>
        <type>exe</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.hudson.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>hudson-rest-model</artifactId>
        <version>${hudson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>QASmoke</id>
        <properties>
            <testcase.groups>testcategories.QASmokeTest</testcase.groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>CTSmoke</id>
        <properties>
            <testcase.groups>testcategories.CTSmokeTest</testcase.groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>PRODSmoke</id>
        <properties>
            <testcase.groups>testcategories.PRODSmokeTest</testcase.groups>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <!-- Applies filtering to properties files, specifically maven.properties (this would be step 2 of 2). The files are output to target/test-resources. -->
            <directory>target/generated-test-resources/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Writes the properties from the maven config into a maven.properties file (in the target/generated-test-resources folder). Most importantly this will write out the webdriver.ie64.driver, 
                webdriver.ie32.driver, etc. properties. This is step 1 of 2 for this file. -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>write-shared-properties</id>
                    <!-- This is specifically generate-resources instead of generate-test-resources to create the proper ordering. -->
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-resources/maven.properties</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <resultsDirectory>allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                <reportDirectory>allure-report</reportDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Fix a compilation issue related to JDK 7 -->
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <groups>${testcase.groups}</groups>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId> <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId> <version>1.5.2</version> <executions> <execution> <id>output-html</id> <phase>generate-resources</phase> 
                <goals> <goal>process-asciidoc</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Configures eclipse to run the project properties plugin so that Eclipse builds also create the maven.properties file. -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>${lifecycle-mapping.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>1.0-alpha-2</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Maven Goal: - clean test allure:report

Error:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.44.0.0
Listening on port 29928
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 26.752 sec - in testscripts.SampleUITests

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- allure-maven-plugin:2.5:report (default-cli) @ sample-project-acceptance ---
[INFO] Generate Allure report (report) with version 1.4.20
[INFO] Generate Allure report to allure-report
[INFO] Found results directory C:\Users\siyer\workspace\sample-project-acceptance\target\allure-results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.476 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-04T14:26:39-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 66M/347M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.5:report (default-cli) on project sample-project-acceptance: An error has occurred in Allure report generation. Could not generate the report: 'other' is different type of Path -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The error is from `Path` - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299604/creating-a-path-between-two-paths-in-java-using-the-path-class). Could be a bug in the plugin, or a mixup between absolute/relative paths in the POM. (If you run `mvn` with `-X` there will be a stacktrace at the end that might be helpful).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the directory path to ABSOLUTE PATH in your pom.xml will work.

i.e., add ${project.basedir} to all directories

In pom.xml make changes as below

```
<build>
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.properties</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
    <!-- Applies filtering to properties files, specifically maven.properties (this would be step 2 of 2). The files are output to target/test-resources. -->
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-test-resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.properties</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Hope this will fix your issue.