# sonarlint doesn't work when Intellij IDEA is not install on C: drive in windows

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I have 2 installations of IntelliJ IDEA, one on C: drive and one on another drive (F:). I have installed on both the SonarLint plugin and it works only on the C: drive installation.

The is ['other' has different roor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFyNh.jpg) and I think has to do with the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16300578).

The error stacktrace is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'other' has different root
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.relativize(WindowsPath.java:392)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.relativize(WindowsPath.java:44)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.util.SonarLintUtils.getRelativePath(SonarLintUtils.java:383)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.issue.IssueManager.wasAnalyzed(IssueManager.java:108)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.issue.IssueManager.store(IssueManager.java:120)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.issue.IssueManager.store(IssueManager.java:114)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.issue.IssueProcessor.process(IssueProcessor.java:72)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintTask.run(SonarLintTask.java:114)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintUserTask.run(SonarLintUserTask.java:39)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintJobManager.lambda$null$18(SonarLintJobManager.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintJobManager.lambda$runTask$19(SonarLintJobManager.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace? You should find it in the Log tab of the SonarLint Tool View.

Comment: @DuarteMeneses I have added the Starcktrace.

Comment: Thanks, it made much easier to understand the cause. I confirm the bug and I've created a ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that SonarLint for IntelliJ is unable to analyze files that are under a filesystem root other than the one where SonarLint stores its files (in IntelliJ's config directory).

The problem should be fixed soon: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-204.