# Exception during Checkstyle scan in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle, intellij-plugin

I installed Checkstyle-Idea plugin, imported the checkstyle file and ran the scan using my rule from the dropdown. I was greeted with the exception below:

```
Unexpected Exception Caught
The scan failed due to an exception: Exception was thrown while processing /dir/.../Test.java
                Root cause:
                'other' is different type of Path
                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'other' is different type of Path
                at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.relativize(UnixPath.java:429)
                at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.relativize(UnixPath.java:43)
                at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.utils.CommonUtil.relativizeAndNormalizePath(CommonUtil.java:382)
                at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.acceptFileStarted(Checker.java:366)
                at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.processFiles(Checker.java:283)
                at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.process(Checker.java:216)
                at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.service.cmd.OpScan.processAndAudit(OpScan.j... (show balloon)
```

There is no trace of this exception elsewhere on the internet, which is scary. I am using 8.28 version but I tried with other older versions and ran into the same issue. When I imported the checkstyle file, it asked for basedi and suppression rule property which I had defined in the checkstyle file. I entered empty string "" in both the fields.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Any symlinks in the project paths?

Comment: The file for which this exception is thrown is not a symlink.

Comment: I'd report a bug to the plug-in developer. It may be specific to your project structure, so the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with checkstyle + gradle, and found that it's because I used a relative path for the `basedir` property. Changing it to an absolute path should work ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678684/6716368));

```xml
<!-- Doesn't work -->
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="basedir" value="someDirectory" />

<!-- Works -->
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="basedir" value="/home/myuser/someDirectory" />
```